# jquery focus didn't work

Tags: jquery, focus

i want to use focus function in jquery to return to same area of the input after clicking the submit button to change code of captcha,but it didn't return to area of the input,and return to the top of the page,i looked for the same problem here,and tried all but also didn't work
is there anyway to do that correctly,or another method to return to same area of input after clicking by jquery,not DOM?

```
<form action="" method="post">   
    <h4>enter pic code</h4>
    <img src="captcha.php" id="captcha" />
    <br />
    <label><a  href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src='captcha.php?'+Math.random();"
id="change-image">change captcha code</a></label>
    <input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha-form" />
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#change-image").focus();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src='captcha.php?'+Math.random(); return false;"`

adding `return false;` is very important when working with event bindings to prevent default behaviour.

Comment: Great. I'm glad it worked! If you have a sec, you may want to see the other comment someone posted to you. More people will be willing to help you out if you officially accept answers. I believe Joseph Silber's answer will also work for you, if you want to be more in the style of jQuery.

Comment: that's true,i used the joseph snippet also,and l like all people here,stack save my life always......

Comment: Yes, SO is absolutely a life-saver!